# Impacts of including too many jar files in classpath

Tags: java, jar

I have a big jar file that has a lot of dependencies on other jar files ~40 files totaling a few hundred MB.  I'm worried about dependencies issues with this jar file so I would like the to add the required dependencies to the Manifest file of this jar at compile time.  I'm wondering if there are negative drawbacks to this approach.  I've done some testing on class load times and they don't really seem to be affected all that much.

Another reason I want to move the dependencies into the jar's manifest is that with so many files the command line gets long and hard to read.  We have a lot of -XX options etc. as well being passed into the JVM but it looks like there isn't a way to set these in the manifest or in some sort of configuration file though.

Comment: Personally I'd always use a trivial script to start the program instead of manually writing all the options and jar files by hand (ugh). That solves all the problems at once, although there's nothing really against adding the jars in the manifest.

Comment: Voo - Thanks for the comment. I currently use a script and my two issues are that when looking at running processes it gets to a point where every instance of java takes up almost a full terminal window.  Second is that others are free to use this jar and may invoke it as they wish.  I would prefer if there is a link between compile and runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you depend on these jars, then it's OK. 40 dependencies is not that much, actually, so don't consider that a problem. Just make sure you don't include unused dependencies.

Comment: I don't see why unused deps would make any problem. Sure they blow up the size a bit (and are unnecessary), but since the classloader is lazy I don't see why that'd be much of a problem.

Comment: I think that is probably the crux of my question.  Linking the dependencies in the jar will definitely mean having unused jars.  Depending on how the jar is used many may not be exercised.  I know that in cases like this splitting up the jar would be ideal.  Unfortunately that is not an option in this case.